# Groovy: how to avoid "org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface fromCache" lines in log output?

Tags: groovy

I am writing a Groovy Script that pulls misc. info from files in a git repository and it is using JSonSlurper to pull data from JSON files and XmlSlurper to do the same for XML files.

Things are all working fine except that all my log statements emit unwanted messages during the run that all look like so:

```
Aug. 14, 2023 3:05:27 PM **org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface fromCache**
INFO: --- actual log statement here ---
```

I.e. each and every log output line is prefixed by such a line. I am using a java.util.logging.Logger for logging.

Any idea anyone what these statements are trying to convey to me and how one can avoid these annoying outputs?

**Addition:**
Based on the first answer I added this to my code but I am still getting these outputs:

```
    static { // silence the annoying groovy indy log output:
        System.setProperty("groovy.indy.logging", "false")
    }
```

Even setting this on the VM command line via `-Dgroovy.indy.logging=false` did not help. Any wisdom how to switch these log-statements off?

**2nd addition:**
These log statements are a tough cookie! I added the suggested statement `Logger.getLogger(org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.class.getName()).setLevel( Level.SEVERE )` to the class' static initializer (i.e. `static { ... }` - as above), to the object instance initializer (i.e. `{ ... }`), at the begin of the main() method and I surrounded the creation and execution of the parsing with it like so:

```
            Logger.getLogger(org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.SEVERE)
            def json = new JsonSlurper()
            Logger.getLogger(org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.SEVERE)
            rootNode = json.parse(new StringReader(content))
            Logger.getLogger(org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.SEVERE)
```

and I am *still* getting these log outputs. Now I am really puzzled!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/vmplugin/v8/IndyInterface.html

> This class provides a logging ability by using the boolean system property `groovy.indy.logging`.

removing this system property or setting it to false should resolve your problem.

https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/vmplugin/v8/IndyInterface.java#L126

```java
        if (Boolean.getBoolean("groovy.indy.logging")) {
            LOG.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            enableLogger = true;
        }
```

Comment: I added an addendum to my question (since it contains a code-snippet which can't be added to a comment). I tried to set that mentioned flag to false but I am still getting these log outputs from the indy code. Any ideas?

Comment: there is a great possibility that your statis executed after indy static. the idea to set this in java/groovy startup.

Comment: as a dynamic option you can try to do something like this in code:  `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.class.getName()).setLevel( Level.SEVERE )`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still no joy - see my 2nd addition to the question.

Comment: sounds something is setting this logger on. how you are running your groovy code? why you are using indy?

Comment: As I just found out these "fromCache" lines are emitted not by any of the "slurpers" but by my log statements! I.e. each and every log-statement actually emits TWO lines, namely this annoying "indy" message and the actual log message. I thus gave the append a new title and removed the text where I suspected Xml- or JsonSlurper to be the culprit.
Re. why I am using "indy": I don't do that consciously. It's obviously called or used internally when I execute that code as a Java application. Maybe that's added by the IDE (Eclipse?)

Comment: It also happens when I start the application outside the IDE, i.e. when I start it using ``java -jar myapplication.jar`. I suspect that's the Groovy library then that's compiled into this app.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem goes away if I set a log format in my Groovy code, for example:

```
System.properties['java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format'] = '%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$-6s %5$s%6$s%n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and ended up switching to the `@Slf4j` annotation instead. The slf4j logger seems to work better overall, as this switch also fixed another annoyance with the `@Log` annotation where logs would sometimes not show up in realtime. No extra logging lines or timing issues with the `@Slf4j`, though.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class MyClass { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I use logback-classic:1.2.10 with slf4j, and fix this problem by this code

```java
static {
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger loggerOfScript =
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyScript.class) as ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
        def context = loggerOfScript.getLoggerContext()
        context.getFrameworkPackages().add(IndyInterface.class.getPackage().getName())
    }
```